# Script issue in J Meter while recording script using 'BAD BOY' tool

Tags: jmeter

[Chrome Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymu6F.png)

HI All - I am new to J meter and i am continuously getting the script error while recording the script using bad boy tool.

I tried with the changing the chrome settings as above:

but still am getting the same script error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope when you normal browse the application then your are not getting the error.

So, if you are recording and getting pop-up but you can proceed further then record your action and suppress the javascript error from Preference>Automatically handle>Javascript Error Dialogs.

You can also disable recording javascript request from Preferences>Recording option. Since, jmeter work on request and response and not GUI level so javascript is not supported. It does not actually parse/execute JavaScript coming with the loaded page.

Also, try the option you have shown to disable script in IE browser and then try with chrome.

Hope this helps.